# Overlapped I/O: some functions are still missing

Tags: c++, c, windows

One of the things that I really like in Windows API is overlapped I/O. I've written dozens of network servers using overlapped I/O (for both sockets and files) with only a limited number of threads. I'm also a driver writer, so that I know well how overlapped I/O is implemented "behind the scenes".

The only thing that always bothered me is that some API functions don't support overlapped mode. For instance, creating a file (i.e. calling `CreateFile`) always works synchronously. This is pity, because those methods could support overlapped (asynchronous) mode as well. For instance, when a file is created (or opened) - the file system driver receives an `IRP_MJ_CREATE` request, for which it may (and usually does) return `STATUS_PENDING`.

My question is: is there an option to open the file asynchronously nevertheless? (but please don't tell me to create another thread to open the file).

Comment: You said it yourself. If it's missing, it can't be done because there is no system call for it. Maybe you could write a driver which emulates asynchronous file creation?

Comment: Writing an additional driver is a nice. I just hoped there exists an API I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that no asynchronous version exists because `CreateFile` is fundamentally a blocking operation: http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=484 (scroll down to Creates Are Even More Cancellable):

> ***Creates Are Even More Cancellable***
>
> As you can imagine,
>   creates are a bit of a special
>   operation within the O/S. One
>   particularly interesting point is that
>   they are always handled synchronously
>   within the I/O Manager, so there is no
>   way to send an asynchronous create
>   operation. Also, in previous versions
>   of the O/S, the I/O Manager performed
>   a non-alertable kernel wait if the
>   create request was pended from within
>   a driver. Therefore, even terminating
>   the thread was not enough to cancel a
>   create request that the user felt was
>   taking too long.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This probably answers my question.

Comment: @valdo, yeah. I bet that if you bound the number of outstanding CreateFile calls in progress to the number of threads running, you prevent a malicious program from flooding the operating system with too many asynchronous CreateFile calls. Since CreateFile is such a heavyweight function (accessing metadata, possibly living on a network, etc.), it helps to reduce the number you can have in flight. Since they would end up being processed serially anyway.

Comment: I'm just curious why this is so. I have a "theory". Opened file system objects are actually "device" instances created by the corresponding device drivers. Unfortunately I/O manager is designed in such a way that it returns you a `HANDLE` to the created device instance only after the corresponding driver handled its creation.

Comment: Theoretically this could be designed better. First you could "allocate" an abstract `HANDLE`. Next you "bind" it to the requested file system object (this is where FS driver is involved), and that operation could be asynchronous. Since you **already** have the  `HANDLE` - voila! You can monitor its status and, optionally, abort it at will.

Comment: @MSN: I can't accept the argument about "security" issues. There're so many other "heavy" calls that can "spam" the system at once. I believe there should be another reason.

Comment: @valdo, I don't work at MS anymore, so I can't even begin to determine why it happens to be synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but there is no way to open a file asynchronously without using a separate thread.

Comment: Pity... Yet another problem with opening the file asynchronously from different thread is that you don't actually have a way to **abort** the file opening attempt. You may kill that thread, but this in turn adds a lot of mess (such as problems with per-thread DLLs init/uninit, thread stack is not freed and etc.)

Comment: On Vista and later, at least, perhaps `CancelSynchronousIo()` can be used for that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with I/O completion ports is that (a) you have too little freedom and (b) despite being in the kernel, it is far from being optimal. TrustLeap has made a lot of noise about these performance issues recently, when comparing Windows to Linux.

Too sad that Microsoft does not follow-up (TrustLeap said Bill Stapples claimed that IIS users did not want performances and rather wanted more productivity).

I guess that these positions define the platforms.

Comment: And who said I'm going to use completion ports? There're different completion mechanisms: (a) competion ports, (b) waitable events, (c) user APCs.

Comment: you're right when you say that completion ports "limit the freedom" in some sense. But calling synchronous function (which **blocks** you - hence steals the control from you) is no freedom at all, right?